# Javascript JSON Dynamic Parent

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic 1 app, I do not know if there is a way but for example, here, is there a way I can dynamically assign a parent in this JSON object depending on the value of the Variable?

```
var contact = {
     "Name": "John Doe",
     "available": true,
      Variable: [ 
       {
           "Location": "Home",
           "Number": "33"
       },
       {
           "Location": "Work",
           "Number": "22"
       }
     ]
};
```

Lets say Variable = "friends"
Then

```
var contact = {
     "Name": "John Doe",
     "available": true,
     "Friends": [ 
       {
           "Location": "Home",
           "Number": "33"
       },
       {
           "Location": "Work",
           "Number": "22"
       }
     ]
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use braces notation `[]` and put variable in it.

```
var contact = {
   "Name": "John Doe",
   "available": true,
};
contact[Variable] = [ 
   {
       "Location": "Home",
       "Number": "33"
   },
   {
       "Location": "Work",
       "Number": "22"
   }
 ]
```

---

If using *ES6* you can use [Computer Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) `[Variable]: {}`

```
var Variable = 'Friends';
var contact = {
 "Name": "John Doe",
 "available": true,
 [Variable]: [ 
   {
       "Location": "Home",
       "Number": "33"
   },
   {
       "Location": "Work",
       "Number": "22"
   }
 ]
};
```

Comment: HI I just noticed, I am using ionic 1, and it did not run on devices that had Android < 4.4 but it ran on newer devices. any other alternative?